# measuring wall time in a multi-threaded environment

Tags: c++, linux

Is there a way to measure the wall time between two points in a multi-threaded program in milli-seconds resolution? I am familiar with boost time_t, but its resolution is seconds, not milli-seconds. Methods from MKL library are welcome.

Comment: There are several platform-specific solution available, so please specify yours.

Comment: The fact that your program is multi-threaded shouldn't matter if you're measuring wall time. A clock should read the same from any thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On any modern POSIX system (like Linux), call [clock_gettime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html) with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.

[update]

By "wall time", I assume you mean the time that actually elapses between two points.  If you mean reading the actual time of day, use `CLOCK_REALTIME` instead of `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.  (The difference is how they behave if the user should change the system clock in the middle of your measurement.  `CLOCK_REALTIME` will reflect that change while `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` will not.)

[update 2]

C++11 has built-in facilities for this in the [std::chrono namespace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration).  So if you have C++11, that is the most portable and future-proof option.